# Array comparision in php to get only difference

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

Following Below are two arrays which i wanna compare and remove the same values something like array_diff() Function and i want to store the result in third array

```
$array1 = Array([0] => Array([a] => XYZ,[b] => ABC))
$array2 = Array([0] => Array([a] => XYZ,[b] => ABC),[1] => Array([a] => PQR,[b] => XYZ))
$array3 = array_diff($array1,$array2);
//$array3 value must return this value Array([1] => Array[a]=> PQR,[b] => XYZ)
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong but i am getting error that array cannot be converted into string. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that your `$array2` will always contain more elements than `$array1` then here is your solution:

```
$array1 = array(array('a' => 'XYZ','b' => 'ABC'));
$array2 = array(array('a' => 'XYZ','b' => 'ABC'),array('a' => 'PQR','b' => 'XYZ'));
$limit = count($array2);
$array3 = array();
for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++){
  if(empty($array1[$i]))
    $array3[] = $array2[$i];

  $array3[] = array_diff($array1[$i],$array2[$i]);
}
foreach($array3 as $k=>$a3){
  if(empty($a3)||($a3===NULL))
    continue;
  $result[$k] = $a3;
}
var_dump($result); //array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { ["a"]=> string(3) "PQR" ["b"]=> string(3) "XYZ" } }
```

Please note that array_diff works on 1D array and you was providing 2D arrays as parameter and that's why it wasn't working.

Also your way of defining `$array1` and `$array2` is wrong, please check this solution for right syntax.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thanks Abhay Maurya your solution really help me

Comment: No Problem, Happy Coding!